# Configure EF Core with F#

Tags: entity-framework, f#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to set up EF Core with F#.
My DbContext looks like this

```
type MainContext(options : DbContextOptions<MainContext>) =
    inherit DbContext(options)

    [<DefaultValue()>] val mutable dokumenter : DbSet<Dokument>
    member x.Dokumenter with get() = x.dokumenter and set v = x.dokumenter <- v
```

and in Startup.fs:

```
   member this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        services.AddDbContext<MainContext>(fun options -> options.UseInMemoryDatabase()) |> ignore
```

which gives the following compilation error:

`No overloads match for method 'AddDbContext'. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window).`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `|>` ignore after `UseInMemoryDatabase()` did the trick:

```
services.AddDbContext<MainContext>(fun options -> options.UseInMemoryDatabase() |> ignore) |> ignore
```